# Different Stored Procedures run parallel?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created two procedure (1st and 2nd) with different functions. But these two procedure insert data to one table. If I have two application users and the first user run 1st procedure and the second user run 2nd Procedure. I would like to know that these two procedure will run parallel or not.

Comment: Different applications => different connections => parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Store Procedures writing to the same table can run in parallel.

There are certain conditions that you must be aware of to execute seamlessly.

To get clarity on this we need to understand the [transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in DBMS.

Every action that you perform in a database goes through a transaction. A transaction will try to acquire a lock on a resource that it is trying to make the changes. When another process is also making a lock request to the same resource that has an open transaction, then [Deadlock](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-deadlock-definition-in-sql-server/) will occur. To avoid this we need to alter the DBMS [isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-ver15).

There is a possibility that your process may result in deadlock if you are updating(soft delete) or deleting(hard delete) a record in the same table at the same time from 2 different points, but a plain insert will not face any issues in most of the DB settings.

Please vote up if you find this answer helpful.